# Annotate .png figures in a geom_boxplot when x-axis is a discrete variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations

I would like to annotate small .png figures in a geom_box plot in ggplot.
For example use the dataset:

```
diam <- dplyr::select(diamonds, cut, price)
ggplot(diam, aes(x= cut, y= price, color= cut))+
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

So the questions are:
**1) how can I upload figures from my local file;

2) how can I define the positions of these five figures when x-axis is a discrete variable.**
Thank you.

Comment: Does `geom_image` from the [ggimage package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggimage/vignettes/ggimage.html) work for you?

Comment: @Z.Lin Hi, thank you for your comment, it is quite helpful for me!